# OS X: boost++ regex conflicts between static and dynamic linked versions -> EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, boost, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I have an OS X bundle that is statically linking the boost++ regex library.
This bundle is loaded into a host application which itself loads a dylib which is containing another version of boost++ regex.

When I try to create a regex in my bundle:

```
regex expr(exprString, icase);
```

I get a crash:

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Exception Codes:       EXC_I386_GPFLT

The call stack shows that my bundle tries to call the boost::re_detail::basic_regex_parser not from the statically linked boost version of my bundle but from the boost version of the host application.

Call Stack:

```
0   libProToolsInterplayOption.dylib    0x0000000114c06c9f boost::re_detail::basic_regex_parser<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::parse_extended() + 15
1   com.my_bundle.AAX   0x0000000125f802af boost::re_detail::basic_regex_parser<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::parse(char const*, char const*, unsigned int) + 575
2   com.my_bundle.AAX   0x0000000125f6f412 boost::re_detail::basic_regex_implementation<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int) + 130
3   com.my_bundle.AAX   0x0000000125f6f217 boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int) + 487
4   com.my_bundle.AAX   0x0000000125dd027b boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int) + 43 (basic_regex.hpp:380)
5   com.my_bundle.AAX   0x0000000125dd0243 boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >& boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::assign<std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int) + 99 (basic_regex.hpp:418)
6   com.my_bundle.AAX   0x0000000125dd0173 boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::basic_regex<std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int) + 51 (basic_regex.hpp:393)
7   com.my_bundle.AAX   0x0000000125dce783 boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::basic_regex<std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int) + 35 (basic_regex.hpp:394)
```

This yields EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

How can I make sure that my bundle is only using the statically linked version of boost for all it's function calls?

Note: I have no control if the host application that is loading my bundle is using boost or which version of boost it is loading.

Any help appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: I believe I have the same issue. Have you been able to solve it yet?